# 'DRY' jQuery click functions

Tags: jquery, dry

I have an unordered list of links which all correspond to different events in my JS file. Right now I am using

```
$('#gst').click(function(){
    preset(gst);
});
$('#gsd').click(function(){
    preset(gsd);
});
$('#ts').click(function(){
    preset(ts);
});
$('#none').click(function(){
    preset(none);
});
```

Here is my preset function:

```
function preset(setter){
if(setter === gst){
    currentPreset = gTitle;
    $('#count').html(currentPreset);
}else if(setter === gsd){
currentPreset = gDesc;
}else if(setter === ts){
currentPreset = tLimit;
}else{
currentPreset = none;
$('#count').html(currentPreset);
}
}
```

and it looks horrible. I know there is a 'DRY' way to do this. But I have not found one. Does anyone know the best way to do this? It would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: how does your preset function look like?

Comment: Added, sorry about formatting. Pasted the code.

Comment: use a class or multiple expression selector, and to differentiate use the html5 unobtrusive way `data-atributes` in the element that fires the event like `data-setter="gst"` and inside your js just get it by `$(this).attr('data-setter')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#gst, #gsd, #ts, #none").click(function(){
    preset(this.id);
});
```

Comment: You're very welcome :) As some of the other have said, you may see benefit from using a class, and assigning said class to all elements you wish to use this clickable feature on. The reason I didn't cover that in my answer was because you appeared to be looking for a static solution, hope it's okay for you :).

Answer (score 3):

```
function handleClick() {
    preset(window[$(this).attr('id')]);
}

$('#gst, #gsd, #ts, #none').click(handleClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make preset take a string as its parameter then do something along the lines of

```
$('.classGivenToAll').click(function() {
    preset($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

I get id in this way in case you wanted to switch out for any other attribute.